# Number of Service's impact on application's efficiency

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've used 3 services in my android application.

1st Service: Listening to broadcast receivers.

2nd: In this service, I've used a Runnable, which runs every second to fetch the details of foreground application.

3rd: Uploading the data into server.

Now, I need to develop a library project which has above application's functionality.

Any services or receivers used in a library project will have to be declared in the Client application's manifest file. Here comes my questions:

1. Can I use Threads instead of services so that I can skip the problems of declaring services definition into manifest files?? How ever, I'll have to use one service to implement broad cast listeners.
2. Does number of services used in an application impacts on application's efficiency?? Because, Client's application might have one or two Services. If they wishes to include my library, then their number of services will be raised to 4 or 5. This will be a definite problem.
3. If I use Threads whose life cycle is dependent on application's process, will I be having problems of getting it killed if there's no memory?? Services will get restarted if it gets killed but I do not know how to encounter this problem if I use threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- **Threads and services are meant for diferent type of operations.** For example a Foreground service would be to stream audio/video, a ThreadPool would be use for downloading lot of images and display them in imageviews (UniversalImageLoader, Volley) For single/simple operations you can use Asynctask, but when you need several threads you would prefer classic Threads and Handlers.

2- **You can use several services in one application** it won't affect the performance. Of course it depends on the quality of your code and the way the services interact with each others. For exemple in one of my application I use a service for downloads, 1 for connectivity, 1 for streaming live audio and audio files and 1 to manage these two. With that I use intent and broadcast receiver. **No lags.**

3- If application is killed, background services are killed too. **It's up to you** to terminate your threads cleanly in onDestroy() for example or with a broadcast receiver you can listen to the kill intent.

Comment: U said u have an application with 4 services. If u were supposed to add my plugin, then would u?? Coz, my plugin will add another 3 services, that makes totally 7 services in ur application.

Comment: If there are no conflict between those services, and they must be complementary. If two or more have the same purpose then one of those is not necessary (example : 2 services for downloading json is not a good idea you should regroup them in a single one).

Answer (score 0):

Threads are much simplier than Services. Actually, it's a complicated task - to communicate with thread, while for service you simply bind to it and call it's method regularly. Moreover, threads don't have a Context instance, so you are very limited with Android functionality.

I can advise you to use Threads for small compact tasks which are time-expensive so that it won't freeze the main thread. AsyncTask - for more complicated, parametrized tasks with easier way to get the result(while Thread should use handlers to post in UI thread). And, finally, Services - for long-term tasks which lifecycle must not depend on any other object as they are running in background and owned by Android itself. Thus many activities and even applications can share the same service and use it.

I do recommend you to use Service. I don't think 3 services you describes have a significant influence on the app performance.

Comment: What I'm concerned about is, if I ask my clients to include 3 more services into their application, will there be any reason for them to reject?? Will number of services leads to rejections??

Comment: @madhu no, it's fine to ask clients to make changes in the manifest file, just describe properly why are you asking them to do so

Comment: Is there any source confirming services impact on application's efficiency?? Just to be on the safer side.

Comment: @madhu I can't find any, but as well I have no problems with running multiple services in app untill the demand reasonable amount of memory(the rarest resource on the device))